# How can one trigger save in Google document?

Tags: google-docs

Google documents are automatically saved when the user made modifications to the documents. However, if the Internet connection is poor, after around one minute the user might see:

[image]

and the user would then lose their modifications is google document isn't able to connect again.

How can one trigger save in Google document (So that one doesn't have to wait for google document to realize it doesn't have access to Internet anymore)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can press Ctrl-S to force a save as you would do with MS-Word/Excel etc...

Looking at your screenshot, its always a good idea to enable offline mode. It will capture all your changes locally and sync them up when the connection comes back.

To turn on hit the Menu icon in the top left of the screen and select Settings. Then click the 'Offline' button so its blue like below.

[image: Offline Mode]